# How can I beat "The Rise of Africa" campaign?

Tags: fate-of-the-world

I am trying to accomplish the mission "The Rise of Africa" but I failed already 3 times because, at the end of period (2045), HDI index is not increased over requested target.

I am new to the game, can you please explain me how can I manage to finish that mission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After approximately ten tries, this is what I've *finally* got:

2020. - **NA**: 2 agents, welfare, enviro offices
      - **SA**: 2 agents, enviro office
2021. - **NA**: 1 agent, water management, medical welfare, political office
      - **SA**: 1 agent, water management, welfare office, political office
2022. - **NA**: 1 agent, security assistance, educational enrollment, enh. water infrastructure, medical welfare
      - **SA**: 1 agent, security assistance, transport, medical welfare, drought
2023. - **NA**: 2 agents, job-sharing, drought, storm, security assistance, educational enrollment, medical welfare
      - **SA**: 1 agent, storm, transport, medical welfare, impr. drought, enh. water
2024. - **NA**: transport, impr. drought, impr. storm, baby boom, security assistance, educational enrollment (I stopped job-sharing)
      - **SA**: 1 agent, educational enrollment, transport efficiency, medical welfare, job-sharing, grow commerce, grow industry

End result: 0.70 HDI for SA, 0.73 HDI for NA. I *think* I had easy mode enabled.

A note: should you still lose, it may be faster to load the autosave and change the cards in the last turn until things work, rather than starting every time from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I understood that I recruited too less agents while they key is recruiting at least 2 each turn, with a bit more focus on NA. Final result 0.76 NA 0.73 SA